# Error when saving with numpy.save and loading with pickle.load

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

I've saved a simple numpy array by doing:

```
numpy.save(filepath, anarray)
```

I'm now trying to retrieve it using pickle (I don't want to switch to numpy.load because the code has to be flexible), but I get:

```
atuple = pickle.load(open(filepath, 'rb'))

_pickle.UnpicklingError: STACK_GLOBAL requires str
```

Answer (score 1):

Numpy and pickle use different file formats. There's no reason to expect that you should be able to unpickle an array saved using `np.save`. If you need to be able to load things with pickle, you should save them with pickle.

Comment: why does numpy.save have a default True allow_pickle option then ? also, [numpy.load](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.load.html) explicitly says that "Load arrays or pickled objects from .npy, .npz or **pickled files**."

Does this mean that when dumping with pickle one can retrieve with numpy but not the opposite ?

Comment: If the array contains `objects` it can use `pickle` to serialize (and retrieve) them.  Conversely `pickle` of an array uses the `save` to serialize it.  So they are related.  But it doesn't mean that files are wholely compatible.

Comment: @hpaulj I didn't know that pickle was using `save` as part of its implementation. That's cool! I think the point that this doesn't imply compatibility is important, though. You can save CSV inside of a JSON object, but that doesn't mean you'll be able to load it with a CSV reader.

Comment: @duff18 the `allow_pickle` option has to do with whether to allow saving or loading arrays with elements that are python objects (as opposed to eg numpy numeric types). Unpickling can execute arbitrary and potentially malicious code. `allow_pickle=False` is a guard against this, not a pickle compatibility setting.